# How to use jquery to create element with conditional class on the element?

Tags: jquery

I've got this so far:

```
days.forEach(function(day) {
 $("<div>" + day.day + "</div>")
    .addClass("day")
    .appendTo("#days");  
});
```

I want to be able to check

```
if(day.events.length > 0)
```

then add additional class of "hasEvent". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of your stuff, just like at the airport!

```
var elem = $("<div>"+day.day+"</div>");
elem.addClass("day");
if( day.events.length > 0) elem.addClass("hasEvent");
elem.appendTo("#days");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
days.forEach(function(day) {
  var curr = $("<div>" + day.day + "</div>");
  if(day.events.length > 0)
  {
     curr.addClass('hasEvent');
  }
  curr.addClass("day").appendTo("#days");  
});
```

Comment: oh wow, I completely forgot I can create it on the fly with jquery and  assign it to a variable. Thanks a ton!